# jqGrid Sort - Browser hangs for bigger data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I have a requirement where I have to load the complete data(30,000 rows) in jqgrid, data is able to load successfully. However after complete loading of data if I click on sort, browser hangs for few seconds and then loads the grid properly with sorted data. Is their any way I can stop the browser hang or show a loading icon when sort takes place.

Any suggestions to handle sort for huge data in jqGrid

I'm using a static data to load the grid, and 500 records are fetched and loaded at a time.

My grid code is as -

```
$('#demo').jqGrid({                     
                    datastr : 'json',
                    datatype : "local",
                    sortable: true,
                    sortname : sortcol,
                    sortorder : asc, //sort order
                    colModel : colModelGrid, //Creating the grid model before jqgrid
                    page : 1,
                    height : '100%',
                    width : gridTotalWidth,
                    rowNum : 500,
                    rowTotal : bugCountTotal,
                    loadOnce : true,
                    loadui : "disable",
                    loadtext : "Loading...",
                    rownumbers : true,
                    //define column models
                    pager : '#' + pagerInfo, //set your pager div id
                    viewrecords : false, 
                    search : true,
                    rowList : rowInfo,
                    caption : 'Complete Report',
                    scroll : true, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
                    emptyrecords : 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom

                    data : bugDetails, //variable that stores complete data - Static data
                    beforeRequest : function () {
                        //Show Spinner
                    },
                    loadComplete : function (data) {
                        //Hide Spinner
                        return;
                    },
                    loadError : function (r, st, error) {
                        console.log("Error Loading Grid.");
                    },

                });
```

Comment: To show an info while sorting you can use the [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) `onSortCol` (_Raised immediately after sortable column was clicked and before sorting the data_) and `gridComplete` (_This fires after all the data is loaded into the grid and all other processes are complete. Also the event fires independent from the datatype parameter and after sorting paging and etc._)

Comment: How many rows can be displayed on your monitor? Would be not better to reduce the value of `rowNum` till 20-30? It's very important to know not only the number of rows, but the number of columns which you have. It's important to specify, which version jqGrid and which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). If you write "Browser hangs" you should write which web browser (IE, Crome) and in which version (IE6, IE8, IE11) you used in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I find the most important to reduce the number of rows in the page. The choice of `rowNum : 500` is very bad. No monitor can display so much rows. Other important aspect for the performance is the number of columns. It's more important aspect as the number of rows. Additionally it's very important to mention which web browser you use in your tests. The performance of Google Chrome can't is much better as the performance of IE8 for example. All questions should write which version of jqGrid and which fork you used in your tests.

I made for you [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-30000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) which demonstrates the time of loading, sorting and filtering of the grid with 13 columns and 30000 rows displayed in 20 rows per page. I used [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop. You can test it in the browser, which is the most important for you and to see the expected performance. The code is very simple. You can play more with the performance using http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/1rmmyeLh/9/. The code uses

```
rowNum: 20
```

I recommend you to try to reduce `rowNum` value in your application and to modify (at least temporary for the test) the URLs to the jqGrid files to free jqGrid URLs described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). You should see the performance advantage.